# How to speed up Ajax requests Python Youtube scraper

Tags: python, ajax, youtube, comments, lxml

I'm editing on a simple scraper that crawls a Youtube video's comment page. The crawler uses Ajax to go through every comment on a Youtube Videos comment page and then saves them to a json file. Even with small number of comments (< 10), it still takes 3+ min for the comments to be parsed.

I've tried including `request-cache` and using `ujson` instead of `json` to see if there are any benefits but there's no noticeable difference.

Here's the code I'm using currently:

```
import os
import sys
import time
import ujson
import requests
import requests_cache
import argparse
import lxml.html

requests_cache.install_cache('comment_cache')

from lxml.cssselect import CSSSelector

YOUTUBE_COMMENTS_URL = 'https://www.youtube.com/all_comments?v={youtube_id}'
YOUTUBE_COMMENTS_AJAX_URL = 'https://www.youtube.com/comment_ajax'


def find_value(html, key, num_chars=2):
    pos_begin = html.find(key) + len(key) + num_chars
    pos_end = html.find('"', pos_begin)
    return html[pos_begin: pos_end]


def extract_comments(html):
    tree = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
    item_sel = CSSSelector('.comment-item')
    text_sel = CSSSelector('.comment-text-content')
    photo_sel = CSSSelector('.user-photo')


    for item in item_sel(tree):
        yield {'cid': item.get('data-cid'),
               'name': item.get('data-name'),
               'ytid': item.get('data-aid'),
               'text': text_sel(item)[0].text_content(),
               'photo': photo_sel(item)[0].get('src')}


def extract_reply_cids(html):
    tree = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
    sel = CSSSelector('.comment-replies-header > .load-comments')
    return [i.get('data-cid') for i in sel(tree)]


def ajax_request(session, url, params, data, retries=10, sleep=20):
    for _ in range(retries):
        response = session.post(url, params=params, data=data)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            response_dict = ujson.loads(response.text)
            return response_dict.get('page_token', None), response_dict['html_content']
        else:
            time.sleep(sleep)


def download_comments(youtube_id, sleep=1, order_by_time=True):
    session = requests.Session()

    # Get Youtube page with initial comments
    response = session.get(YOUTUBE_COMMENTS_URL.format(youtube_id=youtube_id))
    html = response.text
    reply_cids = extract_reply_cids(html)

    ret_cids = []
    for comment in extract_comments(html):
        ret_cids.append(comment['cid'])
        yield comment

    page_token = find_value(html, 'data-token')
    session_token = find_value(html, 'XSRF_TOKEN', 4)

    first_iteration = True

    # Get remaining comments (the same as pressing the 'Show more' button)
    while page_token:
        data = {'video_id': youtube_id,
                'session_token': session_token}

        params = {'action_load_comments': 1,
                  'order_by_time': order_by_time,
                  'filter': youtube_id}

        if order_by_time and first_iteration:
            params['order_menu'] = True
        else:
            data['page_token'] = page_token

        response = ajax_request(session, YOUTUBE_COMMENTS_AJAX_URL, params, data)
        if not response:
            break

        page_token, html = response

        reply_cids += extract_reply_cids(html)
        for comment in extract_comments(html):
            if comment['cid'] not in ret_cids:
                ret_cids.append(comment['cid'])
                yield comment

        first_iteration = False
        time.sleep(sleep)

    # Get replies (the same as pressing the 'View all X replies' link)
    for cid in reply_cids:
        data = {'comment_id': cid,
                'video_id': youtube_id,
                'can_reply': 1,
                'session_token': session_token}

        params = {'action_load_replies': 1,
                  'order_by_time': order_by_time,
                  'filter': youtube_id,
                  'tab': 'inbox'}

        response = ajax_request(session, YOUTUBE_COMMENTS_AJAX_URL, params, data)
        if not response:
            break

        _, html = response

        for comment in extract_comments(html):
            if comment['cid'] not in ret_cids:
                ret_cids.append(comment['cid'])
                yield comment
        time.sleep(sleep)


def main(argv):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False, description=('Download Youtube comments without using the Youtube API'))
    parser.add_argument('--help', '-h', action='help', default=argparse.SUPPRESS, help='Show this help message and exit')
    parser.add_argument('--youtubeid', '-y', help='ID of Youtube video for which to download the comments')
    parser.add_argument('--output', '-o', help='Output filename (output format is line delimited JSON)')
    parser.add_argument('--timeorder', '-t', action='store_true', help='Download Youtube comments ordered by time')

    try:
        args = parser.parse_args(argv)

        youtube_id = args.youtubeid
        output = args.output

        start_time = time.time()

        if not youtube_id or not output:
            parser.print_usage()
            raise ValueError('you need to specify a Youtube ID and an output filename')

        print 'Downloading Youtube comments for video:', youtube_id
        count = 0
        with open(output, 'wb') as fp:
            for comment in download_comments(youtube_id, order_by_time=bool(args.timeorder)):
                print >> fp, ujson.dumps(comment, escape_forward_slashes=False)
                count += 1
                sys.stdout.write('Downloaded %d comment(s)\r' % count)
                sys.stdout.flush()

        elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time

        print '\nDone! Elapsed time (seconds):', elapsed_time


    except Exception, e:
        print 'Error:', str(e)
        sys.exit(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

I'm new to Python so I'm not sure where the bottlenecks are. The finished script will be used to parse through 100,000+ comments so performance is a large factor.

- Would using multithreading solve the issue? And if so how would I refactor this to benefit from it?
- Is this strictly a network issue?

Comment: Excuse me, but how did you figure out the correct parameters and data you need to insert to "session.post" in order to get a proper response from the 'https://www.youtube.com/comment_ajax' url? I can't find any documentation on this url/API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Yes, Multithreading will speed up the process. Run the network operations (ie. downloading) in a separate `Thread`.
- Yes, it is a network related issue.

Your requests are I/O bound. You make a request to Youtube - it takes some time to get back the response, it's dependent mostly on the network, you can't make the process faster. However, you can use `Thread`s to send multiple requests in parallel. That will not make the actual process faster but you will process more in less time.

Threading tutorial:

- https://pymotw.com/2/threading/
- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm

An example somewhat similar to your task -- http://www.toptal.com/python/beginners-guide-to-concurrency-and-parallelism-in-python

Also since you will be doing a lot of scraping and processing, I would recommend using something like [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) - I personally use it for these kind of tasks.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I've done some more testing and strangely, the process runs much faster with more comments. For 95 total comments the total time dropped to 9 sec (0.09 sec per comment). For 330 comments it is only 42 sec (0.12 sec) to compute. If it as an I/O issue shouldn't the times increase?

Comment: You are extracting multiple comments from one html response. So the more there are on one page, the more you will extract. But downloading the html themselves are I/O issue. The reason I mentioned it to be an overall I/O issue is because you have no control over how many comments there would be on a page. So using `Thread` will make it faster in any cases.

Comment: Ahhh ok thank you! I'll look into it and add an answer in case someone else runs into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Making multiple requests at once will speed up the process, but if it's taking 3 minutes to parse 10 comments you have some other issues and parsing 100,000 comments will take days. Unless there's a pressing reason to use `lxml` I'd suggest you look at [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) and let it provide you with lists of the comment tags and their text content rather than doing it yourself. I'm guessing most of the slowness is in `lxml` transforming the content you pass to it and then in your manual counting to find positions in a string. I'm also suspicious of the calls to `sleep`-- what are those for?

Assuming this

```
print >> fp, ujson.dumps(comment, escape_forward_slashes=False)
count += 1
sys.stdout.write('Downloaded %d comment(s)\r' % count)
```

is just for debugging, move it into `download_comments` and use `logging` so you can turn it on and off. Dumping each individual comment to JSON as you go is going to be slow; you might want to start dumping these into a database now to avoid that. And re-examine why you're doing things one comment at a time: `BeautifulSoup` should give you a full list of comments & their text with each page load so you can handle them in batches which will be handy once you start parsing larger groups.